# How to test if a point is inside an SVG closed path

Tags: javascript, svg, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to put together a drag & drop interface which allows a user to drag a div on a page which is constrained to the inside of an irregular closed SVG path.

Here's an example - the orange square is my draggable element, the gray SVG path is what I want to constrain it to on drop:

```html
<div class="drag-parent">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="141.019" height="74.065" viewBox="0 0 141.019 74.065">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .target {
            fill: #333;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <path id="Path_4569" data-name="Path 4569" class="target" d="M0,0H141.018V74.065h-24.27V37.033H10.88V12.971H0Z"/>
    </svg>


      <div class="draggable" style="width:20px;height:20px;background:orange;cursor:pointer;"></div>  
      </div>
```

What I'd like to do is check the draggable div as it's dragged, to make sure it's completely inside the closed path of my SVG.

I'm using GSAP Draggable to take care of actually dragging the element, but I'm stumped on how to test if it's inside that path or not.

So far I've tried `isPointInFill` however this seems to return true in chrome nomatter what I give it.

I've also tried using `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events on the path which is a great starting point; but when you're dragging something those events don't fire since the mouse pointer is "ontop" of the dragged item rather than the SVG path.

What would be a good way to enforce bounds of an SVG path - or, is there a much simpler way to enforce irregular bounds on dragged items?

Comment: Please read about [DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)

Comment: @enxaneta thanks, I was able to use this in conjunction with setting the pointer-events property of the dragged element to "none" while I check that the mouse position is inside the path I want, this is some way towards figuring it out. Would you consider expanding on this for a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to check if all 4 corners of the orange div are over the path. Maybe I've oversimplified the things since the `drag_parent` has `margin 0; padding:0;``

I hope this is what you were asking.

```js
let D = false,// if D ids true you can drag
m = {},// the mouse position
thePath = document.querySelector("#Path_4569"),
draggable = document.querySelector("#draggable");

draggable.w = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().width;
draggable.h = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().height;

draggable.p0s = [[], [], [], []];//one array for every corner

draggable.delta = {};// distance between the click point and the left upper corner

draggable.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  D = true;
  draggable.delta = oMousePos(draggable, e);
});

drag_parent.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (D == true) {
    let counter = 0;// how many corners are in path
    m = oMousePos(drag_parent, e);
    draggablePoints(m);
    draggable.style.left = draggable.p0s[0][0] + 1 + "px";
    draggable.style.top = draggable.p0s[0][1] + 1 + "px";
    draggable.p0s.map(p => {
      if (document.elementFromPoint(p[0], p[1]) && document.elementFromPoint(p[0], p[1]).id == "Path_4569") {
        counter++;
      }
    });
  
    if (counter == 4) {// if all 4 corners are in path
      thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#777");
    } else {
      thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
    }
  }
});

drag_parent.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  D = false;
});

drag_parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => {
  D = false;
});

function oMousePos(elmt, evt) {
  var ClientRect = elmt.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}

function draggablePoints(m) {
  //top left
  draggable.p0s[0][0] = m.x - draggable.delta.x - 1;
  draggable.p0s[0][1] = m.y - draggable.delta.y - 1;
  //top right
  draggable.p0s[1][0] = m.x - draggable.delta.x + draggable.w + 1;
  draggable.p0s[1][1] = m.y - draggable.delta.y + 1;
  //bottom right
  draggable.p0s[2][0] = m.x - draggable.delta.x + draggable.w + 1;
  draggable.p0s[2][1] = m.y - draggable.delta.y + draggable.h + 1;
  //bottom left
  draggable.p0s[3][0] = m.x - draggable.delta.x + 1;
  draggable.p0s[3][1] = m.y - draggable.delta.y + draggable.h + 1;
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
svg {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
#drag_parent {
  outline: 1px solid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
}
#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag_parent">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="141.019" height="74.065" viewBox="0 0 141.019 74.065">
      <path id="Path_4569" data-name="Path 4569" class="target" d="M0,0H141.018V74.065h-24.27V37.033H10.88V12.971H0Z"/>
  </svg>
      <div id="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A possible simplification might be to just use the draggable divs bounding box in your `draggablePoints` function instead of doing the calculations.